# Sliced object losing all detail in Cura

Tags: slic3r, repetier

I'm pretty new to 3D printing. I am using Repetier Host 2.6 with Slic3r (printer Geeetech i3 Pro B).

When I slice detailed models I get issues like this as the slice result:

[image: Badly sliced model]

This is the model in the example, [Army Men flames of war single version](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2427014).

I can slice simple objects fine, walls, cubes 2D logos etc.

Why is this doing this?

When I used Cura the slice is fine.

Comment: This is a very small model, and you are going to need a very fine nozzle and a very small layer height in order to print it successfully with an FDM printer. Even then, you may not be able to realise all the details. Ideally, it should be printed with a resin printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not "loosing details". What is is is this:

You can not print on air. So, certain things (like the backpack) require SUPPORTS that are removed after printing. Another example is the gun.

Your support setting force the slicer to set up quite a lot of supports and that is what you see - start removing them.

There ALSO is a problem with possibly you using too large a nozzle. Depending on that one you may loose details, but there is not even the basic form visible on your picuture because all I see are supports.

[https://all3dp.com/1/3d-printing-support-structures/#:~:text=3D%20printing%20support%20structures%20are,added%20cost%20to%20the%20model](https://all3dp.com/1/3d-printing-support-structures/#:%7E:text=3D%20printing%20support%20structures%20are,added%20cost%20to%20the%20model). exokauns supports.

Comment: Oh, as addendum: thisis a 15mm model - you may, once you sort out the support issue, consider printing it with a 0.1mm or 0.2mm nozzle. THAT SAID: check the details first ONCE YOU HAVE DETAILS. Not a picture full of support material.